# How to format date to match specific pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to format **DateTime.Now** to match this pattern **Example:** 10-March-2011.

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900208/format-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
```

More formats available [here](http://hunterconcepts.com/tools/developer/formats)

Answer (score 0):

You could look the original [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) regarding dates and times formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");

DateTimeOffset thisDate2 = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 6, 10, 15, 24, 16, 
                                              TimeSpan.Zero);
Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}", 
                   thisDate2); 
// The example displays the following output:
//    Today is June 10, 2011.
//    The current date and time: 06/10/11 15:24:16 +00:00
```

taken verbatim from :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

that particular example would be

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a format string like hunter suggests but if l10n is important to you, you might want to consider:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
```

This will use the locale settings to determine the date format.